# How to slice a long string based on characters in lowercase and add to a list using python?

Tags: python, linux

I have a long string with both Uppercase and Lowercase characters. How can a extract chunks in lowercase and add in a list.
Thanks.

Example:
**Input:**
ATGCAATTAATTGCatgcatgcatgcAAAATTTGGGGCCCCccggttaaatcggatcTGTGCACACTCTAGAGaaaaaaaaattttttt

**Output:**
[atgcatgcatgc,ccggttaaatcggatc,aaaaaaaaattttttt]

Comment: Does this relate to Linux in any other way other than you are perhaps running it on a Linux system?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression along with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ATGCAATTAATTGCatgcatgcatgcAAAATTTGGGGCCCCccggttaaatcggatcTGTGCACACTCTAGAGaaaaaaaaattttttt'
>>> re.findall(r'[a-z]+', s)
['atgcatgcatgc', 'ccggttaaatcggatc', 'aaaaaaaaattttttt']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the islower() method in Python to check if a character is in lowercase or not, and then use a loop to iterate through the string, extracting the lowercase substrings and appending them to a list.

```
input_str = "ATGCAATTAATTGCatgcatgcatgcAAAATTTGGGGCCCCccggttaaatcggatcTGTGCACACTCTAGAGaaaaaaaaattttttt"

result = []
current = ""

for char in input_str:
    if char.islower():
        current += char
    elif current:
        result.append(current)
        current = ""

if current:
    result.append(current)

print(result)
```

The following will be your output

```
['atgcatgcatgc', 'ccggttaaatcggatc', 'aaaaaaaaattttttt']
```

The above code iterates through each character of the input string and checks if it's lowercase or not using the `islower()` method. If it's lowercase, the character is added to the `current` string. If it's not lowercase and `current` is not empty, the `current` string is added to the `result` list and `current` is reset to an empty string. Finally, if `current` is not empty after the loop, it's added to the `result` list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't judge too harshly, but it turned out what you asked

```
def sortletters(letters):

    List_letters = []
    Letters_Lower = ""

    for letter in list(letters):

        if letter == letter.lower():
            Letters_Lower += letter
    
        else:
            if len(list(Letters_Lower)) != 0:
                List_letters.append(Letters_Lower)
                Letters_Lower = ""

    else:
        if len(list(Letters_Lower)) != 0:
            List_letters.append(Letters_Lower)

    return List_letters

if __name__ == '__main__':
    letters = "ATGCAATTAATTGCatgcatgcatgcAAAATTTGGGGCCCCccggttaaatcggatcTGTGCACACTCTAGAGaaaaaaaaattttttt"

    print(sortletters(letters))
```

Output:

```
['atgcatgcatgc', 'ccggttaaatcggatc', 'aaaaaaaaattttttt']
```